# How declare action of Tabbar item?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have drag a Tab-Bar in nib file. Now i want to open new view when click on tab bar item.  Without using tab-Bar controller i want to use tab bar and action on tab bar item. For tab bar i said earlier tab-bar i drag that and next is that How do define or declare action on tab bar item?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.title = @"J.F. 's Library";

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: What? I didn't understand a thing...

Comment: i am saying that i have drag a tabbar and when i click on item then a new view open. how code that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab bar is the sub property of UITabBarController.. Without use of this tabbarController you cAN not set tab bar in it.
IF you partially success for set in NIB file than use SELECTOR method for action of Tab-Bar..